# Why does calling a Tkinter method directly work, but not from another method?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a simple program that for the purposes of this question, is simply opening up a file dialog box to ask the user to select a directory, which I will then use for other purposes. The way I implement this method `getSaveLocation()`, is I have used TKinter to create the main GUI using `Tk()`, hide it using `withdraw()` and then get the directory by using `filedialog.askdirectory()` which will ask the user to select a directory on their computer, and stores that directory path in a variable called directory. This is shown in the code below.

I have included the full program in a pastebin here: [Pastebin Link](https://pastebin.com/B4kc6fnR)

When I call this method `getSaveLocation()` on its own (see pastebin lines 49 and 50 for following) at the bottom, the method works fine. The dialog box is generated and the directory path selected is successfully stored in the directory variable, which I have tested using `print()`.

However, when I instead call this method from another method, say main(), and then run `main()`, nothing happens. In my mind, there seems to be no difference other than modularity.

What am I doing wrong?

```
def getSaveLocation():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
    return directory
```

Comment: You are supposed to call tk.Tk() exactly once in your code, is this your full code?

Comment: The code of your pastebin working for me.

Comment: What OS are you running on?